# Android Staging build flavour trying to connect to React Native packager

Tags: android, react-native, android-build, android-build-flavors

I have introduced two product flavors and a new build type.

However when I run the Staging variant, it still tries to connect to the React Native Metro bundler. I want Staging to adopt the same steps as the Release build type.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    staging {
        initWith release
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
productFlavors {
    // Production
    prodFlavor {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        dimension "builds"
    }
    // Staging
    stagedFlavor {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        dimension "builds"

    }
}
```

I am building this through CircleCI by running `./gradlew assembleStagedFlavorStaging`. The apk builds fine but when I run it on my device I get the following

[image]

I am able to see this due to enabling debuggable. Without this line, the app crashes.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it @Dan ?
isn't this related with https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14400